# Bad Request Error while sending json data to spring mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to send some json data from angular ng grid to spring mvc controller,but i am getting error as **400 (Bad request) The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.** .

This is my Request Paylod:

```
[{"orderId":1,"orderTitle":"Xcel","orderDetail":"cash","orderType":"Xcel","orderPriority":"22.0","retailerId":0,"orderRefno":"9.900499743E9","customerName":"high","customerContactno":"pen drive","customerEmailId":"nutral","paymentType":"iffu@gmail.com","orderStatus":"pen drive","reciptDate":null,"bayNumber":"Xcel","deliveredDate":null,"deliveredBy":"Irfan","updatedOn":null,"pudoOutlet":null,"retailer":null,"outletId":0}]
```

here is my spring mvc controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createorder",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Content-Type=application/json")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView createOrder(@RequestBody Order order){

    System.out.println("hiiiii"+order);
try{


    orderDao.createOrder(order);
    return new ModelAndView("product1.html");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);

}
return new ModelAndView("pr.html");

}
```

here is my angular controller from where i am posting:

```
$scope.save = function() {

    console.log("hii inside save function");
    console.log($scope.mySelections);
    console.log("after myselection")
    var d=$scope.mySelections; 
    console.log("hhhhh" +d);
     $http({

         method: 'POST',

          url: './createorder',
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          data:d

        }).success(function (data) 
          {
            $scope.status=data;
          });
      };
```

I am totally confused why i am getting this error ? Is it because i am sending some null values to spring mvc controller ? if yes how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score -2):

Is Order an inner class? If so, try taking that class into its own file. Worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an independent answer.